# Handle exception which throws when @Pattern annotation is failed

Tags: spring-boot

Class ExceptionHandler (With @ControllerAdvice) extends BasicApiExceptionHandler class (HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException, BindException, Exception). How to return my ResponseEntity with my error message insted standart message with description errors when @Pattern for field isn't valid?

```
public class GeneralRequest {

@Pattern(regexp = "(?i)(en|fr)")
private String lang;

//getter/setter
}
public class MyRequest extends GeneralRequest {

@Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{12}$")
private String contractID;

//getter/setter
}
```

and endpoint in controller:

```
@GetMapping("/contracts/contract")
public Response<DTOClass> getContract(@Valid MyRequest request) throws Exception {

    return new Response<>(errorOK.toString(), 
        ResponseCode.MESSAGE, contractService.getData(reqest));
}
```

When lang paramenter empty/null(not present) I have to assign default value "en". Empty may be any parameter lang and contractID(default value 111 - If parameter not present def.value  to assign.

Comment: Problem resolved.Overrite method)). But I have new. When @Pattern invalid, how to assign default value to field?

Comment: Can you post your code?